# How to retry with delay an Observable inside pipe in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rxjs

I have the following code:

```
notificationsWsSubject.pipe(
    filter((socket): socket is Socket => !!socket),
    switchMap(socket => fromEvent<Socket.DisconnectReason>(socket, 'disconnect')),
    tap(() => wsConnectedSubject.next(false)),
    filter(reason => (['ping timeout', 'transport close', 'transport error'] as Socket.DisconnectReason[]).includes(reason)),
    switchMap(() => signedInObservable),
    switchMap(user => forkJoin([of(user), from(getNotificationsWebsocketTicket())])),
).subscribe(values => {
    // Connect with websocket
}, error  => {
    // Throw error to user
})
```

The general flow:

- Listen to the `disconnect` event in `socket.io-client`
- Proceed if the disconnection cause is due to network error
- Get the currently signed in user from `signedInObservable`
- Generate a ticket in the server by calling `getNotificationsWebsocketTicket()` (and creating an `Observable` from it using `from()`
- Do stuff in `subscribe(value => ... )`

My problem is that I would like to retry the `from(getNotificationsWebsocketTicket())` in case it fails, with a delay of 5 seconds between each failure.
Only after 3 retries I want the entire main observable to fail.

something like:

```
from(getNotificationsWebsocketTicket()).pipe(delayedRetry(3, 5000))
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can do this:

```ts
from(getNotificationsWebsocketTicket()).pipe(
  retryWhen(e$ => e$.pipe(
    take(3),
    delay(5000)
  ))
);
```

`retryWhen` can be a bit of an interesting operator to get your head around. `e$` is an observable that is managed by the `retryWhen` operator. Anytime the source errors, `retryWhen` emits that error to `e$`.

What happens next is up to the observable your lambda returns:

`Errors` are errors,
`Completes` are completes,
BUT emissions (`next`) are a cue to retry

Comment: retryWhen is deprecated.... Use operator retry(retryConfig) with its delay property.... see https://rxjs.dev/api/index/interface/RetryConfig for more details on interface...